# Start Padrino on different host (virtual)

Tags: rack, webrick, padrino

I start WEBrick server through Padrino by this command: `padrino start`

It listens on `localhost`, but I would like to use WEBrick virtual hosts to change this behaviour to respond to other hostnames like `example.com`. But `padrino start` doesn't have these options. How can I pass virtual hosts details to WEBrick?

Answer (score 1):

It actually does have an option to do so.

`bundle exec padrino start -h example.com`

should bind to example.com for listening.